# Touchpad not working after installing a different kernel

Tags: kernel, 22.04, touchpad

So i am on ubuntu 22.04 and it shiped with kernel v 5.19, i needed and acs override patch so i installed the 5.12.2 acso kernel, now when i boot with the acso kernel, my touchpad does not work at all but my usb mouse, and when i boot with the stock kernel both work. I really need to get the touchpad working can somebody please help. I am trying to passthrough a pci device to a vm but there are other devices in the same iommu group, and if there and you have to add the whole group otherwise it wont work, so i have to add them all but my vga compatible controller (basically it displays and renderes images on screen) is in the same iommug group and if i passthrough that device my screen goes black. And thats when the acs patch comes in handy, it allows you to break down these devices in as many groups as possible. But the newest acs kernel that was pre-patched was v 5.12.2 and i had to install that but my touchpad stopped working. For a while it was fine but then i realised i needed to unbind my usb controller from my host (ubuntu) to make it work for my vm, so then all of my usb ports worked on my vm but not on ubuntu, including my usb mouse, thats why i need to get the touchpad working, as it is not a usb device

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1472885/edit) to add more details about your hardware. Also, why do you want to downgrade the kernel? Please explain what you mean by acs override patch, and what you are trying to do.